# Calculating CDF for Dry Days (0mm/day)?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function

I am working on daily precipitation data and need to calculate cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) of daily precipitation data, however, I don’t understand how to transform 0 mm/day (dry days) to CDF.

Recommendation please.

Answer (score 0):

Cumulative distribution function works for a numerical or ordinal variable. "Dry days", understood as a variable with values "dry day"/"not dry day", is not a numerical variable. However, 0 mm/day is a value of the variable "daily precipitation", which is a numerical (continuous) variable.

Therefore, for that variable you can compute $CDF(0) = P(precipitation \le 0)$, that equals the proportion (or percent) of dry days.